# loading gwt app from django

Tags: django, gwt, toolkit

I am trying to load a google web toolkit application with django, but the gwt host page does not seem to work (just a blank screen) when I invoke it with render_to_response() from my django view. I have verified that a plain hello-world html file loads fine from the gwt war directory, so it's not a path issue. Also the host page renders if I manually open it in a browser. I am running my django app in development mode using manage.py runserver. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say you've tried it manually within the browser - is that over HTTP or file:///

Does sound like a path issue, TBH. Have a look in Safari or Firebug to see the HTTP activity when the host page loads. The 'nocache' JS file you include the in the host page loads the appropriate compiled JS for that user agent. Maybe it can't find JS.

Comment: Yea, it is a path issue. Django is not able to find the correct paths to my css and js files. What is the proper way to do this? I have not seen a Django tutorial that says you need to keep special URL patterns for css and js files.

Comment: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/ - and note the warning about how this is for the development server only.